# What is the difference between RCTTypeBulletproof and RCTTypeBulletProof2?

Tags: ringct, bulletproofs

There seems to be two types of bulletproof transactions in monero, was there maybe a bug in the first one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`RCTTypeBulletproof2` adds some additional data (beyond the RCTTypeBulletproof type):

- It changes the field `nbp` to a varint field, which has the count of Bulletproof signatures [[source](https://github.com/monero-project/monero/blob/6335509727661349e50c54c4e0eafd692f0d6907/src/ringct/rctTypes.h#L335)]
- It adds the encrypted amount to each output [[source](https://github.com/monero-project/monero/blob/6335509727661349e50c54c4e0eafd692f0d6907/src/ringct/rctTypes.h#L291)]

Comment: What does "count of bulletproof signatures" mean? The amount of rangeproofs in the tx? Which would be equal to the amount of outputs?

Comment: It should equal the number of outputs, yes.

Comment: Why does it need to be added if we can look at the number of outputs?

Comment: Don't quote me on this, I think it's because there can be a pseudo output which doesn't need a sig.

Comment: Ohh didn't even know pseudoOuts needed signatures. Edit:ohh you mean the intermediate mlsag between pseudoout and real out

Comment: Initially I thought it might have been related to a dummy output not needing a range proof (e.g. for mimicking a two output tx), but on further digging, it doesn't seem to be being used anywhere.